# Dont save item to array if 'input[type='hidden']:first' is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

this code get all data row in my table, however, i dont want to save item on the array if the first hidden input contains no text

```
 $('.save').on("click",function(){    
        var array = $.map($('table tr'), function (val, i) {
                var obj = {}, inputs = $(val).find('td input[type='hidden'],input[type='text'],select');
                obj[inputs.filter('input[type='hidden']:first').val()]
               = $.map(inputs.not('input[type='hidden':first'), 
                function (val, i) {
                    return val.value;
                });
                return obj;
            });
            var data = JSON.stringify(array);
        });
```

this is a sample result of my array :

```
[{"add":["orange","1","Yes"]}[{"":["apple","2","Yes"]}]
```

Notice the second item,it contains empty(not "add"), i dont want it to save on my array. Any help is much appreciated.

see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/8/) here

Comment: can you provide a fiddle

Comment: "contains no text" is a very different criterion to "is undefined", which do you want?

Comment: @Mritunjay see  this fiddle sir

Comment: i mean contains no text for hidden input sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array = $.map($('table tr'), function (val, i) {
     var obj = {},
     inputs = $(val).find('td input[type=\'hidden\'],input[type=\'text\'],select');
     var inputVal = inputs.filter('input[type=\'hidden\']:first').val();
     if (inputVal.length) {
         obj[inputVal] = $.map(inputs.not('input[type=\'hidden\']:first'),
         function (val, i) {
             return val.value;
         });
     }
     return obj;
 }).filter(function (val) {
     return !$.isEmptyObject(val)
 });
```

If you want to exclude empty `arrays`, you'll have to run a `filter` after the `map` call.

Comment: can you check this fiddle sir, i cant work to alert the array http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/8/

Comment: wow thanks sir, but see this http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/10/ if i add the empty flag,value is not saving but the array item is there `[{"add":["orange","1.00","Yes"]},{}]`

Comment: Right, like I mention below the code sample, you have to run a `filter`: http://jsfiddle.net/8kP9y/11/